# Understanding expressions inside switch

Tags: javascript

Consider the following script:

```
var x = 1;

switch (x) {
    case ( ( x+1 ) == 2 ):
        console.log("It works!");
        break;
    default:
        console.log("Nope, not happening.");
        break;
}
```

Now, I've read that expressions inside `case` are evaluated and then compared to the variable. Here, since `x` is 1, `( x+1 ) == 2` evaluates to `TRUE`. Also, the value of `x` (which is 1, originally) in equivalent to `TRUE`. If this reasoning is correct, why am I getting the message "Nope, not happening"?

Please explain.

Comment: because 1 is not "equivalent" with `true`. Switch uses `===` for comparison.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Ah, that's a nice insight! Thanks for the explanation. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't read the signature of the `switch` statement properly. It `switch (x)` asks for an expression `x`, while `case y` asks for a value `y`.

See my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/risto1/3nyqqodv/) and the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch).

Answer (score 2):

Do it this way:

```
var x = 1;

switch (x + 1) {
    case 2:
        console.log("It works!");
        break;
    default:
        console.log("Nope, not happening.");
        break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was trying to understand the intricacies of `switch`.

Comment: The user @risto explains it ;)

Comment: Yes, just saw that. But thanks for your answer too! :)

Answer (score 0):

(X+1)==2 returns true not 1. Use value inside case.